# Unable to connect to Azure VM through RDP but able to connect through Bastion

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I was able to connect to Azure VM through RDP earlier but now suddenly I'm unable to connect to VM through RDP.

I tried to connect through Powersell.

Even powershell script was able to connect earlier but not working now. Myself didn't changed anything in Azure VM.

I'm getting below errors.

[image]

[image]

But I'm able to connect to VM through Bastion.

WinRM is already enabled in Azure VM.

I tried by creating new Azure VM and enabled RDP port 3389 but still getting same connection issue.

How to resolve issue.

Comment: You can follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-nsg-problem) to enable port 3389 in the NSG but change the `Source: Any` to `Source: your client public IP address` when you connect to Azure VM through RDP.

Comment: I tried changing source to ip address but still not working.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - able to connect through bastion in Azure portal, but local rdp client does not work. I have a NSG rule to allow connections to port 3389. I followed this guide: https://jeffbrown.tech/azure-bastion-rdp-native-client/  -  except it errors out when trying to authenticate: ... \cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/network/tunnel.py", line 104, in _get_auth_token
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: org.apache.guacamole.net.auth.credentials.BiFrostVMUnAvailableCredentialsException: VM is either not accessible or not found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When debugging RDP issues one tool I use to test connectivity from a windows client is:

- start
- run
- cmd
- telnet ip port
- e.g telnet 99.99.99.99 3389
- noting you may need to install the telnet client from windows features tool

Try this from multiple locations with different public addresses (including from the VM itself in some circumstances but clearly not for your issue).

Does it connect to the RDP Server listening port ?

If the answer is yes then you know the server is listening.

If the answer is no then the port is likely blocked, service is not available or a routing issue could be the cause.

Thinking out loud review the resources you have sitting in front of the VM:

- window firewall (Disabling all firewall profiles is a more foolproof way of troubleshooting than setting the RDP-specific firewall rule, see REF)
- local network outbound traffic blocks
- firewall in front of the vm

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/enable-disable-firewall-rule-guest-os

Comment: Could you please elaborate on  points window firewall if you can get to it,
local network outbound traffic blocks,
firewall in front of the vm . It would be great
If you provide steps or any useful links.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Windows Firewall on the host you are attempting to get too. I understand this is unlikely being that you are attempting to RDP into that host but I listed it as a cause of RDP blocking issues on remote machine. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/enable-disable-firewall-rule-guest-os

Comment: I figured it out that Issue is with local machine itself not with azure vm.

Comment: thanks for the update John, all the best (ps , its why the telnet test is useful )